# how to make scalatest work with spraytestkit and HttpServiceActor

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I looked at [spray 1.3.1 testkit documentation](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-testkit/) but could not find a proper example for what I need below:
I have this sample `spray 1.3.1` service

```
trait MyService extends HttpServiceActor {
  def receive = runRoute(routes)

  val isAliveRoute = path("isalive") {
    get {
        complete("YES")
    }
  }
  val routes = isAliveRoute
}
```

I'm trying to test it with `spray test-kit` but failing to do so here is my `TestCase`

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MyServiceTest extends FlatSpec with ScalatestRouteTest with ShouldMatchers with MyService {
  "The service" should "return a greeting for GET requests to the isalive" in {
    Get() ~> isAliveRoute ~> check {
      responseAs[String] should be("YES")
    }
  }
}
```

However I get

> Error:(15, 87) illegal inheritance; superclass FlatSpec  is not a
>   subclass of the superclass HttpServiceActor  of the mixin trait
>   MyService class MyServiceTest extends FlatSpec with ScalatestRouteTest
>   with ShouldMatchers with MyService {
>                                                                                         ^
>   ^

and:

> Error:(17, 11) could not find implicit value for parameter ta:
>   MyServiceTest.this.TildeArrow[spray.routing.RequestContext,Unit]
>       Get() ~> isAliveRoute ~> check {
>             ^

Are there ways around this?
Can I have my service `extend HttpServiceActor` and still be able to test it with scalatest and spray testkit? if so how? I want to continue extending HttpServiceActor makes life easier and code more compact and readable.  But I would also like to test it with scalatest.

so i tried updating the code as comment said to split to trait and service as in:
https://github.com/spray/spray-template/blob/on_spray-can_1.1/src/main/scala/com/example/MyService.scala

```
class MyServiceActor extends Actor with MyService {
  def actorRefFactory = context
  def receive = runRoute(routes)
}

trait MyService extends HttpService {

  val isAliveRoute = path("isalive") {
    get {
        complete("OK")
    }
  }
  val routes = isAliveRoute
}




@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MyServiceTest extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers with MyService with ScalatestRouteTest {
  def actorRefFactory = system

  "The service" should "return a greeting for GET requests to the isalive" in {
    Get() ~> isAliveRoute ~> check {
      responseAs[String] should be("YES")
    }
  }
}
```

but i get:

> Testing started at 13:26 ... [DEBUG] [05/14/2014 13:26:25.813]
>   [ScalaTest-run]
>   [EventStream(akka://com-server-web-conf-MyServiceTest)] logger
>   log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started [DEBUG] [05/14/2014 13:26:25.814]
>   [ScalaTest-run]
>   [EventStream(akka://com-server-web-conf-MyServiceTest)] Default
>   Loggers started Request was not handled
>   org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: Request was not handled
>     at
>   spray.testkit.ScalatestInterface$class.failTest(ScalatestInterface.scala:25)
>     at

Comment: It works if you split up your code into the route part which just extends from `HttpService` and move the actor relevant stuff into the concrete class implementing the actor. See how it's done in the spray-template: https://github.com/spray/spray-template/blob/on_spray-can_1.1/src/main/scala/com/example/MyService.scala

Comment: @jrudolph updated question, i tried that it helped, but i still have an error...

Comment: That's now a genuine test failure as your request (`Get()`) didn't handle URLs with an empty path. If you want to have actual failure responses (404) to be generated in that case you have use `Get() ~> sealRoute(isAliveRoute) ~> ...`.

Comment: @jrudolph can be posted as answer..

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with one difference. At complete statement I had sending message to another actor, so I needed actor functionality to test behavior. I solved it that way:

```
trait MyService extends HttpService {
 val myActor: ActorRef
 val homeS: ActorRef 
 (...)
```

and sending message inside get to

```
path("isalive") { get {
ctx: RequestContext => homeS.tell(ctx, myActor ) }
//on homeS actor:
def receive = {
case ctx: RequestContext =>
  ctx.complete( ... )
```

but if you don't need actor functionality of in MyService then better is to do like @jrudolph said in comment.

Full code here: https://github.com/kastoestoramadus/simple_zookeeper.git