# How can I fix the missing implicit value for parameter ta: TildeArrow in a test spec

Tags: scala, routes, spray, scala-2.9, spray-test

I'm working on a simple test spec using spray and I can't get it to compile correctly, don't know if I'm doing anything wrong. My version of scala is 2.9.3 and spray 1.0.1 (Updating either of them is not a suitable option). Here's my test spec's code:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import spray.testkit.Specs2RouteTest
import spray.http._
import akka.util.Duration
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import service.MyProxy

abstract class MyTestSpec extends Specification with Specs2RouteTest with MyProxy{

  val duration = Duration(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  implicit val routeTestTimeout = RouteTestTimeout(duration)

  "MyProxy" should {

    "return a json for GET requests to the /api/getclass/classCode path for a regular request" in {
      Get("/api/getclass/123/") ~> myRoutes~> check {
        responseAs[String] must contain("classCode")
        contentType === ContentTypes.`application/json`
      }
    }

  } // end should...
} //end class
```

I'm getting this error when I run the test.

```
[error] C:\Users\Desktop\Project\MyTestSpec.scala:23: could not find implicit value for parameter ta: MyProxySpec.this.TildeArrow[spray.routing.RequestContext,Unit]
[error]       Get("/api/getclass/123/") ~> myRoutes~> check {
[error]                                         ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compile) Compilation failed
```

I've tried different solutions seen on another questions and nothing seems to work so far.

[Spray.io: Can't compile test spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941358/spray-io-cant-compile-test-spec)

[how to make scalatest work with spraytestkit and HttpServiceActor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649081/how-to-make-scalatest-work-with-spraytestkit-and-httpserviceactor)

[Basic Spray-Testkit usage to test a route does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775106/basic-spray-testkit-usage-to-test-a-route-does-not-work)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/H5hkXuDGWYQ

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/zFUJSVBPM5c

**NOTE:** Just for the record, I'm not using scalatest or scalacheck on this. Is purely a [spray] route test.And MyProxy extends Actor

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941358/spray-io-cant-compile-test-spec helped me.

Answer (score 9):

I just struggled with this problem. To figure it out, I waded through the **Akka HTTP codebase**, which is a jungle of `implicit`s.

My problem seemed to be that without the right secondary `implicit` in place, the correct `TildeArrow` instance wasn't being found. If you look at the code, the `TildeArrow` instance, which is required in the error message, is defined as an [`implicit def injectIntoRoute`](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http-testkit/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/testkit/RouteTest.scala#L141) in the companion object and it requires a whole host of other `implicit`s.

I suggest writing out your code without any of the implicit sugar. This should better help the compiler give you a proper error message:

```
"MyProxy" should {
  "return a json for GET requests to the /api/getclass/classCode path for a regular request" in {
    val request = Get("/api/getclass/123/")
    val requestWithRoutes = request.~>(myRoutes)(TildeArrow.injectIntoRoute)
    requestWithRoutes.~>(check {
      responseAs[String] must contain("classCode")
      contentType === ContentTypes.`application/json`
    })
  }
}
```

I think the reason is that since there's no concrete instance of the `implicit` available, the compiler is trying to satisfy the implicit resolution with the `abstract class TildeArrow`, and the completely unspecified abstract `type`, `ta.Out`, doesn't have a `~>` defined.

In my specific case, I was missing an implicit `ExecutionContextExecutor`, whatever that means.

---

**UPDATE**

Actually, I looked into it further and the problem was that I had an `implicit def ec: ExecutionContextExecutor` declared in my route trait, but [`trait RouteTest`](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http-testkit/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/testkit/RouteTest.scala#L26) defines its name as `executor`, and so when I defined my own to fulfill the missing implicit, I ended up with two of the same implicit.

It's a cute API, but the implicit magic is way out of control, IMO, especially given how cryptic the error messages tend to be.

Answer (score 4):

The ScalatestRouteTest already provides an implicit ActorySystem. Remove the **"implicit"** modifier from your actorRefFactory method and the test should get executed.

[Spray.io: Can't compile test spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941358/spray-io-cant-compile-test-spec)

Comment: This was the case for me.

Answer (score 3):

for akka http:

in my case which refer to [akka-http-microservice](https://github.com/theiterators/akka-http-microservice/blob/master/src/main/scala/AkkaHttpMicroservice.scala)

- the `implicit` modifier of `executionContext` and also need to be removed
- and should reorder the trait like this : `class ServiceSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with Service with ScalatestRouteTest`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the not found implicit error appeared when in my TestCase I also imported `import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global` (which is probably having some sort of `ExecutionContext`).

I fixed it adding the monix scheduler import just in the method where I needed it, not on the top imports.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the precise same error message with Scala 2.10 if `myRoutes` is not actually a route but a `Directive[HNil]`.

I am therefore guessing that in your unshown service.MyProxy class your route does not complete.

ie

```
trait MyProxy extends HttpService {
   val myRoutes = path("foo") 
}
```

Gives this error

```
trait MyProxy extends HttpService {
  val myRoutes = path("foo") {
   complete(StatusCodes.Accepted)
 }
}
```

Does not.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on previous answers given, there are some implicits which shouldn't be declared by any other Trait or class that is extends by your Test Class :

- the ActorSystem
- the ExecutionContext
- the DefaultHostInfo (package akka.http.scaladsl.testkit)
- the ActorMaterializer

if any of these is declared elsewhere than in `ScalatestRouteTest`, you'll have the following error thrown :

```
could not find implicit value for parameter ...TildeArrow[RequestContext, SomethingHereOther]
```

Answer (score 0):

your build.sbt should have dependencies for akka-stream test along with akka test.

then it should get the whatever dependencies.

refer to this doc:-

[scala route test doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/testkit.html)