# Testing Akka-http and getting error: No implicit arguments of type: Emptiness[Seq[Rejection]]

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka, scalatest, akka-http

I have a test using Akka-http which has the error in Intellij `No implicit arguments of type: Emptiness[Seq[Rejection]]`. However the code compiles using `sbt compile` and the test passes using `sbt test`. Even when I run the test from the Intellij it passes. IntelliJ shows the error on the line `rejections should not be empty` or when I use `rejections.should(not).be(empty)`.

First I had a problem using `~>` implicit operator and I fixed by adding `implicit val timeout: RouteTestTimeout = RouteTestTimeout(2 seconds)`. Otherwise I had to explicit use `request.~>(gameRoutes)(TildeArrow.injectIntoRoute)`, as it is saying in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34701083/2096986). I am using the following version on `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.7"
val akkaVersion = "2.6.10"
val scalaTestVersion = "3.2.0"
lazy val akkaHttpVersion = "10.2.2"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % akkaHttpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % akkaHttpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % akkaHttpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http2-support" % akkaHttpVersion
)
```

the test:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.MethodRejection
import akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.{RouteTestTimeout, ScalatestRouteTest}
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers
import org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpec

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class MarshallingJSONSpec
  extends AnyWordSpec
    with Matchers
    with ScalatestRouteTest
    with PlayerJsonProtocol {

  import MarshallingJSON._

  implicit val timeout: RouteTestTimeout = RouteTestTimeout(2 seconds)

  "A Game area map backend" should {
    "not accept other methods than POST and GET and DELETE" in {
      Put("/api/player") ~> gameRoutes ~> check {
        rejections should not be empty // IntteliJ SAYS THERE IS AN ERROR HERE
        // rejections.should(not).be(empty) // SAME

        val methodRejections = rejections.collect {
          case rejection: MethodRejection => rejection
        }
        methodRejections.length shouldBe 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a bug in Intellij. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pynfn.png) I created a tiny project doing what you failed to do, and intellij doesn't recognize what works perfectly from sbt shell.

Comment: thanks for testing! I am using IntelliJ Version: 2020.3 Build: 203.5981.155 from November 30th. So, indeed it is a bug that they have to fix. the latest release is from "1 December 2020" =)

Comment: So am I. With Scala plugin version 2020.3.18

Comment: It's important to remember that IntelliJ uses their own implementation of the Scala 2.x type checker, and it's long had issues with implicits.